# cant update gridview by updating method asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i wrote a code for edit delete and update a gridview but its  didnt work during updating its just got the past values not new 
here the server side code:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            TextBox na = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Controls[0];
            TextBox i = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Controls[0];
            TextBox sid = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0];
            //      string a = name.Text;
            string name = na.Text;
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(i.Text);
            String stdid = sid.Text;


            String query = "update [table] set name=@name,stdid=@stdid where id=@id ";
            SqlConnection sqc = new SqlConnection(cons);
            SqlCommand qu = new SqlCommand(query, sqc);
            qu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            qu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stdid", stdid);
            qu.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            string f = qu.CommandText;
            sqc.Open();
            qu.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqc.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ee) { }
        refresh_dgv();
    }
```

and there is my client side cod:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"     OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
         <Columns>

                <asp:BoundField DataField="id"  HeaderText ="id"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="stdid" HeaderText="stdid" />  

            </Columns>  
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you show your Connection String?

Comment: @s.akbari  static String cons = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\uni\internet\homeworcks\tamrin6\IECH_HW6_9250030_GHORBANI_ALI\IECH_HW6_9250030_GHORBANI_ALI\alighorbani_dataview1\dataview.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

Comment: @DurgeshPandey   there is no error just when i enter the updated values in the data gridview text boxes that appear after click on edit link it got the old values

Comment: what is the your table name, please check...

Comment: **CommandType** is missing in your code might be this causes the issue

Comment: @DurgeshPandey the problem is not table name

Comment: qu.CommandType  = CommandType.Text; add this line it'll work

Comment: @Curiousdev the problem is with the first three lines in serverside code that got the old values

Comment: @alighorbani ohh ok than just set Enableviewstate property to false for gridview and check you can get new value

Comment: I think you should call refresh_dgv(); funchion just after sqc.Close();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can solve in multiple ways as below.

**1.**
We have to check if the Page is posted back or not. If not, then we will bind the Grid.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}
```

**2.**
Use **DataKeys**
eg.

```
 <asp:gridview id="GridView1" 
    ...
              DataKeyNames="ProjectID"
    />
 string empsname = Convert.ToString(grdvw1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[1]);
```

**3.**

**Enableviewstate** property to **false** of **gridview** you can get new value